# Using CSS to gain separate control of outer divs of 3

Tags: css

i have a 3x? grid of divs.  I want to select div's marked **a** and apply margin-left:-20px; also I would like to select divs marked **b** and apply margin-right:-20px;

http://jsfiddle.net/98qVL/18/ *Here's an example.*

What is the most efficient semantic way to accomplish this?

Comment: `papayawhip` is a great color, possibly better than my long time favorite `firebrick`.

Comment: well usually a `first` class for the a divs and a `last` class for the b divs does the job

Comment: Loving `papayawhip` and `firebrick`. `Steelblue` is another great color, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select elements in CSS by their content.

However, to do what you're trying to do, you *could* use `nth-child` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/98qVL/19/):

```
.grid:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: red;
}
.grid:nth-child(3n) {
    background: blue;
}​
```

The first part selects every element with the class `grid` that *immediately succeeds* every third element with the class `grid` and applies a red background. This selector also includes the first element, thanks to the `+1`.

The second part selects every third `grid` element and applies a blue background.

Use this to your advantage to apply margins where they need to be applied. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/98qVL/19/) the demo again.

Comment: lotsa love it was that pesky +1 that got me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with `nth-child` selector, if you didn't want to add separate classes to each `div`.

For instance

```
#parent .grid:nth-child(3n+1){
    background:blue; }

#parent .grid:nth-child(3n+3){
    background:red; }
```

would do what you want.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/98qVL/21/

This article gives a good overview of how `:nth-child` works: 
http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: thank you for you quick replay i give you +1 however other answer was more complete thank again so much